# Top Game Developers

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image]

#### Top Game Developers

**Back Story**

Okay fellow puzzlers, I hope you packed your lunch, this one is my most challenging puzzle to date...

Johnny is writing an article about some of the top-selling mobile apps released in the past year. Using only the clues that I provided, help him match each app to its developer, month or release and estimated number of sales. ( yes, most of my puzzles are developer related :)  )

> **Clues**

**1.** The app released in March doesn't have exactly 5.5 million downloads.

**2.** The app released in May is either the game released by Trebuchet or the game with 2.3 million downloads.

**3.** The game released by Digibits was released 1 month earlier than the application with 4.2 million downloads.

**4.** Flowcarts was released earlier than the game with 2.3 million downloads.

**5.** The game with 6.8 million downloads wasn't developed by Trebuchet.

**6.** Bubble Bombs wasn't developed by Novio.

**7.** Bubble Bombs is either the game released in August or the application released in September.

**8.** Of the application released by BeGamez and the game with 4.2 million downloads, one is Wizard World and the other was released in July.

**9.** The app with 5.5 million downloads was released earlier than Castle Crunch.

**10.** The app released in August, the application with 7.2 million downloads, the app with 6.8 million downloads, the app released by Gadingo and the game with 4.2 million downloads are all different apps.

**11.** The application released by Gadingo was released 1 month later than the game released by BeGamez.

**12.** Angry Ants wasn't developed by Trebuchet.

**13.** Flowcarts was released 2 months earlier than Bubble Bombs.

**14.** Of the game released in September and the game released by Digibits, one is Vitalinks and the other has 2.3 million downloads.

**15.** The app with 8.9 million downloads was released 3 months earlier than the application released by Vortia.

**16.** The game with 8.9 million downloads was released 1 month later than Wizard World.

**17.** The application released in March doesn't have exactly 6.8 million downloads.

> **Puzzle Data**

The categories and items for this puzzle are listed in the "Hint: Puzzle Grid" below.

**Hint: Puzzle Grid**

> [image: Puzzle Grid]

**Hint: Blank Answer Grid**

If you want a BLANK answer Grid, here it is:

> [image: Blank Answer Grid]

Source: [Puzzle Baron](http://www.logic-puzzles.org/pdf/E267WP.pdf)

Comment: The linked interactive grid is for a different puzzle?

Comment: Please don't put things like "for geniuses", "very difficult", "super-interesting", etc., in puzzle titles. It's better to let solvers decide how difficult, interesting, etc., a puzzle is. If you really think the puzzle is particularly unusual somehow, a simple note to that effect in the puzzle text suffices. Thanks!

Comment: Good constructive critisism. It was more in jest, of course, the puzzle is very do-able. But, note taken. Thank you.

Comment: The interactive grid, you must configure yourself. It is a template for you to insert your own puzzle data. The link I provided shows sample data for you to get stated. If you wish use that, simply insert the puzzle data in my Hint.

Comment: @JohnS. good to see you again, my friend! Nice puzzle.

Comment: @JohnS. is my answer correct? If so, can you accept it - if not can you say so, so I can keep working on it?

Comment: Is this puzzle from Puzzle Baron?

Comment: It _is_! I just found it!

Comment: I have flagged this for closing as it is the same as Puzzle Baron's logic puzzle of ID E267WP which can be found by Googling `"puzzle baron" "novio"` and clicking the top result (PDF of "4x7 Logic Puzzle - Logic Puzzles") which is the exact same puzzle in a different format. If you go to Puzzle Baron's website, you'll be able to get the exact grids that John S. posted here if you keep randomly generating new puzzles.

Comment: Here's a link: www.logic-puzzles.org/pdf/E267WP.pdf | Obviously, they randomize some of the numbers, but that's what this puzzle is!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the grid - it helped me out.

Here's my solution:

> [image]

with the grid:

> [image]

Comment: You posted first but we got different answers

Comment: This is the solution that I got. I think it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> [image]

Step - by - step

1. > [image]
2. > [image]
3. > [image]
4. > [image]
5. > [image]
6. > [image]
7. > [image]
8. > [image]
9. > [image]

Comment: your solution breaks clue #3

Comment: I may have gone wrong somewhere, but that's not it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... what do you mean that's not it?

Comment: I don't think rule #3 is the rule that's broken.

Comment: 3.) The game released by Digibits was released 1 month earlier than the application with 4.2 million downloads. rot13(Lbh unir Qvtvovgf nf Ivgnyvaxf, juvpu jnf eryrnfrq va Nhthfg; lbh unir Ohooyr Obzof eryrnfrq va Frcgrzore (bar zbagu yngre) fb gung, ol ehyr guerr, fubhyq unir 4.2 zvy qbjaybnqf, jurer lbh unir vg nf 2.3))

Comment: I don't? I have rot13(Qvtvovgf va whzr naq gur tnzr jvgu 4.3Z qbjaybnqf va whyl.)

Comment: Ah, there's the issue. rot13(Va gur obggbz lbh unir Qvtvovgf zngpuvat jvgu Ivgnyvaxf, naq tbvat hc gb gur gbc yrsg lbh unir Ivgnyvaxf va Nhthfg, ohg gura va gur obk gb gur vzzrqvngr evtug lbh unir Qvtvovgf va Whar zngpuvat hc gb Pnfgyr Pehapu.)